# Extracting web elements using Pyquery, Requests and Gadget selector

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, python-requests, pyquery

I am able to extract table values from this [website](https://finviz.com/screener.ashx) with the following code.

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
import requests

url = "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx"
content = requests.get(url).content
doc = pq(content)
Tickers = doc(".screener-link-primary").text()

print(Tickers)
```

But I am able to extract only the first 20 values. There is a 'next' button at the end of the page which has the link to the next set of values.

How can I extract this link automatically, fetch the new page and extract the new set of values and append to my existing list?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through all pages like:

```
counter = 1

while True:
    url = "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&r=%d" % counter
    content = requests.get(url).content
    counter += 20
```

Note that for the first page `r` parameter (which I guess stands for starting entry index) will be `1` for the second - `21`, for the third -`41`... So I used `+ 20` increment for `counter`

You should also add `break` for the moment when the last page reached. Usually one make a check whether new data to scrape available and if not - `break`